# How to provide the proper access to admin and member on their id and password in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have create a login page, from that login page  admin and member can perform login by entering respected login username and password.. In that I wanted to provide the different access to admin and member , i.e.
1.  **For Admin**: Admin can access all the data from that group means he can add financial institute and member details.
2.  **For Member**: Member cannot access all those data he can just view that available data from financial institute and other members detail but he can edit his own information ..

For that I have use the **if loop**….
Here is the code for all the access for admin after login:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var list = from instituteinformation in db.InstituteInformationDBS
                       join addresscontact in db.AddressAndContactDBS
                       on instituteinformation.Id equals addresscontact.Id

                       join bankinformation in db.BankInformationDBS
                       on instituteinformation.Id equals bankinformation.Id

                       where instituteinformation.Id.Equals(addresscontact.Id)
                       select new FinancialInstituteWrapper
                       {
                           ObjInstituteInformation=instituteinformation,
                           objAddressAndContact=addresscontact,
                           objBankInformation=bankinformation
                       };
            return View(list);
        }
```

**View:**

```
<h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Institute Name
        </th>

        <th>
            Owners FirstName
        </th>

        <th>
            Owners LastName
        </th>

        <th>
            Address 
        </th>
</tr>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
                <td>
            <%:Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ObjInstituteInformation.InstituteName) %>
        </td>

        <td>
            <%:Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ObjInstituteInformation.OwnersFirstName) %>
        </td>

        <td>
            <%:Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ObjInstituteInformation.OwnersLastName) %>
        </td>

        <td>
            <%:Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.objAddressAndContact.AddressLine1) %>,
            <%:Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.objAddressAndContact.AddressLine2) %>
        </td>
<td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id=item.ObjInstituteInformation.Id  }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id=item.ObjInstituteInformation.Id  }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id=item.ObjInstituteInformation.Id  }) %>
        </td>
</tr>
<% } %>

</table>
```

After Admin login Financial Institute will be display the following  in index page:

```
InstituteName     FirstName   LastName   Address
ABC                ABC          ABC       ABC          Edit   Details   Delete
```

And if member logins by there id and pass the it should be display like this:

```
   InstituteName     FirstName   LastName   Address
    ABC              ABC              ABC     ABC
```

For that, I want the code in  view like this

```
    <h2>Index</h2>

        <p>
    <%if(Admin id and password){%>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    <%} else{%>
cant create the new institute
<%}%>
        </p>
```

please tell me how to do this.....

I have created the login page like this:

```
public class Login
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }


Controller:

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Login login, MemberBasicInformation memberlogin, string returnUrl)
        {
            using (WrapperDB db = new WrapperDB())
            {
                string usename = memberlogin.UserName;
                string pass = memberlogin.Password;
                bool userValid = db.MemberBasicInformationDBS.Any(user => user.UserName == usename && user.Password == pass);

                if (userValid)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usename, false);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else if (login.UserName.Equals("admin") && login.Password.Equals("admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect Credentials!!");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
For MemberLogin username and password will be taken fro the following model:


public class MemberBasicInformation
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MemberFirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MemberLastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Qualification { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get;set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add for the Security you ask Two things you could choose
first in controller like this

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
 public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

or if you don't want to make the validation on the model.In your View for specific Items you want to make it appear like Specific

inside

```
  @if (User.IsInRole){
         <li>some thing</li>
}
```

but you should make role for Users in second example I've tried it and it is work fine

Comment: but i didn't specify any role in login

Comment: It's Better to do this in case in future you will have several permission for each level to apply for I've the same case by the way in Project

Comment: can u please tell me how to create Roles

Comment: Here when i use the above code as u sugesst then it will logs in successfully to the home page but when i click to the actionlink (financialinstitute) then it again open elready created login page from AccountController(PreDefined).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
User.IsInRole("roleName")
```

On your views to isolate code for a determinated role. This could be used, for example, to hide buttons from users without permissions to use them.

On your controllers you could use

```
[Authorized(Roles = "RoleList")] 
public ActionResult yourAction(){}
```

to allow users within one or several roles to execute your different actions, and you can also use User.IsInRole to get a more detailed level of access within your code.

Comment: can i use the if loop in view just like this <p>
    <%if(Admin id and password){%>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    <%} else if(member login){%>
cant create the new institute
<%}%>
        </p>

Comment: I think it's better to use something like <p><% if(User.IsInRole("Admin") { %> <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %> <% } else { %> cant create the new institute <%}%>